# How to read radiobutton value in Excel sheet to object array

Tags: c#, excel-2010

I have to read data from Excel sheets and upload it to database. Everything works fine except radiobutton fields. In some excel sheets I have radiobuttons. And i want to read yes to object array if radiobutton of value yes is clicked.

Here is the code to read excel value to object array:

```
Range Rrow = ws.UsedRange.Cells.Rows;
object[,] myvalues = null;            
myvalues = (Rrow.Cells.Rows.Value);
```

where ws is the name of worksheet.

I got null value in the position of radiobutton.

i have mapped values into database using the below codde

```
 objInv.FIName = dtExcel.Tables[1].Rows[39][0].ToString();
```

Pls help me in reading values from radio button in excel sheet to object array.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't have 50 rep yet and can't ask for clarification, I'm hoping this will help you.

First, if you are using Form controls, link the radio buttons to cells and read the cell value (cell value will be 0 for none of the radio buttons linked to it being selected, 1 for the first, 2 for the second, etc.).  Then it would be a matter of going through your list of linked cells.

Second, if you are using ActiveX controls, the ActiveX controls each have unique names.  To view the properties of the ActiveX controls, right-click on the control in question and select the Properties option.  To check if an ActiveX radio button control is selected, refer to Sheet1.OptionButton1.Value where Sheet1 is the sheet that has the control and OptionButton1 is the name of the control.  Values are False (not checked) or True (checked).

Depending on the number of radio buttons you need to read from and the type of radio button (form versus ActiveX) will determine the best way to move the values into your database.